# pass data from controller to view without reloading Laravel 5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1

On a button click I am sending a `post request` via `ajax` to my `controller`. Different button click will send different value via `ajax` to my `controller`. And in the controller I am retrieving data from the database. I want to send this data every time the button is clicked to my view so I can use it. I want to send the data without loading the page if possible. How I can do it? I do not want to use `return view('viewname')`. Currently I am injecting the controller to my view but on button click value is changed and hence the data from db too. May be I have to constantly check for value in my view? Any hint from where I can start it. I am a beginner in JS.

**My controller Method**

```
public function getUserMessages(Request $request){
            $id = (int)$request->request->get('id');
        $messages = Message::where('message_by' , $id)->get();

        return $messages;
    }
```

**View**

```
<div class="display-messages-area">
                @foreach($messages->getUserMessages($request) as $message)
                    <span style="color: #000;" class="{{$message->message_by==Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->id ? "pull-right" :""}}">{{$message->message}}</span><br>
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

Comment: Post the code you're working with

Comment: @Patrick2607 i updated the question with code.

Comment: you have a big problem about logic. Controller should call view, not inverse

Comment: @manix no that's not right. What will you do when you need the data from view in the controller so you can process it and return? You can do both.

Comment: What is the code for your ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by learning more ajax and the solution was using `ajax success function`. So in the success function I loaded the data returned from `controller` in my `div`.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'a',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function(data){
                        var x;
                        for(x in data){
                            $("#div1").append(data[x]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```